# Pitivi poor video quality

Tags: video, pitivi

I've been trying to use Pitivi to edit videos, but so far have been completely unable to persuade it to render them at anything like the source file quality

For example:
Source file 1 minute length, bitrate 13.5Mb/s, file size 116.6MB.

I have tried numerous settings on Pitivi and no matter how high I set the bitrate it flatly refuses to go above a bit less than 4Mb/s - file size around 19MB.

I'm happy for the output to be .avi, .mkv, .mp4 or anything similar(but not .mov!).

Is Pitivi really incapable of producing high quality videos, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What settings have you tried altering (you probably need to adjust the project settings etc)? You may also want to try Avidemux or Kdenlive instead

Comment: I've tried lots! The best bitrate I've manged is around 9Mb/s - and all results are blocky & pixillated.
I have tried just about every video editor in sight - both in Linux & Windows. All have their strengths & weaknesses. The best I have found for my purposes so far is Openshot. But it's looking like Pitivi is incapable of producing high quality video.

Comment: You may need to try a different export format (or installing codecs) - what formats have you tried, and which version of pitivi are you using? Using the 0.94 version I managed to export a 1080p video...

Comment: I think I've got there! Previously I tried to update it with apt-get install & was told that I had the latest version - obviously the repository is a little behind the times. Now I've managed to find v 0.94 & on the first test got a good result. May need a bit more tweaking but I think I can now add it to my usable editors.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to adjust two bunch of settings - the project settings:
[image]

and the render settings:
[image]

(With both check the audio settings as well, and when rendering select the appropriate output format and codec, then you could try the advanced settings')

Bear in mind if you make it to high quality many devices may have difficulty playing/rendering it - though rendering a HD version and using ffmpeg to make lower quality versions could work well. Also if you do test renders with smaller chunks of video means you can tweak the settings until you get the result you want, and then you can save a preset so you can use those settings later.

Using Pitivi 0.94, with everything possible related to codecs, gstreamer (see [here](http://www.pitivi.org/manual/gstreamer.html) for why) and ffmpeg installed. The manual is available [here](http://www.pitivi.org/manual/).